# I want to redirect subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com/directory using DNS

Tags: dns

I own 2 domain names "domain1.com" and "domain2.com", I want to redirect subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com/directory using DNS (preferably). Can anyone assist (I am an amateur at domain management)?

Comment: Depends on your registrar, and may require premium DNS. Email them.

Comment: @byde: What's "premium DNS" in this sense? AFAIK DNS cannot handle subdirectories/paths. So this is not possible using DNS alone.

Comment: It is possible, checkout http://dyn.com/support/webhops-and-redirections/ sorry my 1st comment was brief.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple redirect pointing subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com/directory.

In order to do this open your public_html folder. 
You will see a .htaccess file present under the public_html folder.

Add this code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subfolder/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I do not have access to domain1.com htaccess because I only own the domain for that, which is why I am searching for DNS configuration. +1 for the answer though. :)

Comment: @Vivin: so you have a DNS entry for domain1.com, a DNS entry for domain2.com, and a server handling requests for domain2.com?

Comment: @Vivin: You can contact your domain registrar for domain1 and ask them to point or redirect your domain name to the desired web address and yes this can be done. :)

You can do this yourself if you have been provided a domain management panel by your current registrar which provides the redirection feature.

Answer (score 0):

Some premium dns providers provide extra features at dns level such as [Dyn](http://dyn.com/) do.

[Quote on Dyn's Webhop service](http://dyn.com/support/webhops-and-redirections/)

> Redirecting a Subdomain to a Subdirectory
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> `http://myhost.dyndns.org/` 
>   redirects to
>   `http://myserver.dyndns.org/~myhomepage/`
>
> In many instances, you may wish to redirect from a subdomain (e.g.
>   subdom.domain.com) to a subdirectory of your main site (e.g.
>   www.domain.com/subdir). While creating a WebHop redirect is a simple
>   enough solution, a better solution is to use either virtual hosting or
>   a 301 server-side redirection instead..

While the quote isn't a 100% match it should in theory and gives you an idea that 'somethings' can be done at dns level, however they do advise that this should ideally be done at hosting level, if you do consider this a viable solution ensure you question them beforehand as I do not have firsthand experience but have heard of others doing it a similar way.